# Disable hardwired chrome hot key ctrl+w?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, hotkeys

Using Chrome's Remote Desktop I would like to pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to an application on the other PC but that actually closes my Chrome window. Any way of disabling shortcut keys in Chrome?

I searched through the web but didn't find any hacks. I added the shortcut manager extension but that can't manage the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut or some other shortcuts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Only solution that worked for me was to rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to some extension keyboard shortcut.

1. Go to `chrome://extensions`.
2. At bottom right look for keyboard extensions.
3. Add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as shortcut to any Chrome extension you like.

Now, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> does not close the browser tab.

Comment: This is perfect for me, but I didn't have any spare extensions to map to. So I wrote one! It's called "ctrlw". It provides two commands, one which does nothing (to map to ctrl+w) and one which closes the window (which I map to alt-w). Problem solved!

Comment: Just to note, the "Keyboard shortcuts" option is now in the menu (opened by clicking the menu button in the top-left), or you can go directly to chrome://extensions/shortcuts.

Comment: @samson's ctrlw extension can be found on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrlw/goejokenmdamcapadhgghgpeeaeaaedc/ but do look at other extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-ctrl-w/jfknaapblnppeflfamkegnnonlfgokhp and  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-keyboard-shortcut/aidbmcboeighgdnilpdljbedbbiocphj/

Comment: I recommend "CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs" extension which allows Command+W serve as "alt-tab among Chrome tabs"

Answer (score 9):

It's extremely annoying since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the vim equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

I wrote this little Tampermonkey script to temporarily place an event listener on the page unload event:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       disable ctrl+w
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  disable ctrl+w
// @match      http://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){

    // NOTE: ctrl key is sent here, but ctrl+W is not
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
    
        var stopEvilCtrlW = function(e) {
            return "Oopsies, Chrome!";
        },  clearEvilCtrlW = function() {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', stopEvilCtrlW, false);  
        };
    
        setTimeout(clearEvilCtrlW, 1000);
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', stopEvilCtrlW, false);
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Or instead of `ctrlKey` check and 1 second timeout we can test `event.keyCode == 17` in `keydown` and `keyup` and set a boolean flag to check later in `beforeunload`

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> key is used in the nano editor on linux systems.

When using crosh in Google chrome this key combination results in a prompt to close the current window.

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Works for me when connecting to remote systems via SSH using crosh.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP questions, but it's just what i was looking for, how to use vim in the Chrome SSH terminal.  Thanks!

Comment: CTRL + ALT + W didn't work for me, but CTRL + SHIFT + W worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am an extensive VIM user, and I had the same issue. Installing "Chrome Remote Desktop" app and using it to connect instead of using "Google Chrome" tab resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears none of these answers worked for me.

The stackoverflow robot seems to not be able to understand so I add this:

TL;DR

**The only solution that seems to allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to get to the Bash terminal is full screen in Chrome remote desktop.**
[image]

I use Bash and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is kill word backwards when in emacs mode for the command prompt.

If I open Chrome remote desktop full screen mode then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> does the right thing.

Otherwise it closes the tab and if set to an extension the way someone suggested it would open the extension.

The only solution that seems to allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to get to the Bash terminal is full screen in Chrome remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions don't work anymore. I want to use nano text editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> key in my Linode Lish Web GUI, in order to search for a text, I need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> key but that just terminated my window.

In Chrome browser, if you pin the browser window, then if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> it will also close the browser window.

But, in Opera browser, if you pin the browser window, then if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> it will not close the browser window.

So, my solution is to use Opera browser.

Answer (score 0):

On the your system on which CRD window opens, create custom keyboard shortcut "Do nothing" enter echo as a command. Bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. It disables it. Just tried a second ago and it worked.