# Conflict of Shortcuts between Chrome Browser and Nano Editor

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, nano

Using the AWS System Manager, I'm connected to a Linux session. While using the Nano text editor, when I try to search using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, it closes Chrome's current tab.

Without moving to another browser, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/billchurch/webssh2/issues/267

Comment: There are already lots of workarounds for this. It's not exactly a new problem.

Comment: Move to another editor! Seriously though, _vi_ sounds like the perfect fit for this use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable hardwired chrome hot key ctrl+w?](https://superuser.com/questions/569248/disable-hardwired-chrome-hot-key-ctrlw)